# table sorter filter and toggle hidden row not working together

Tags: javascript, filter, jquery-select2, tablesorter

I have tablesorter version which has filter options which works perfectly with these option

```
 $('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            widthFixed: true,
            sortList: [[5,1]],
            widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter'],
            widgetOptions : {
                filter_formatter : {
                    1 : function($cell, indx) {
                        return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
                            match : false // exact match only
                        });
                    },
                    2 : function($cell, indx) {
                        return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
                            match : true,         // adds "filter-match" to header
                            cellText : 'Match: ', // Cell text
                            width: '85%',         // adjusted width to allow for cell text
                            value: ['Lassosum','P&T','P&G'] // initial values
                        });
                    }
                },

                // option added in v2.16.0

            }

        });
```

So I want to hide a couple of rows initially and then display them with checkboxes 
And I have

```
$options.on('change', function() {
              var $elementsToToggle = $('.' + this.value);
              if (this.checked) {
                $elementsToToggle.show();
                console.log("its checked");
                $("tablesorter").trigger("updateAll");


              } else {
                  console.log("its checked");
                $elementsToToggle.each(function() {
                  var hide = true,
                      elementToToggle = this;

                  $options.each(function() {
                    var optionClass = this.value,
                        optionValue = this.checked;
                    if (elementToToggle.classList.contains(optionClass) && optionValue)
                      hide = false;
                  });

                  if (hide === true)
                    $(elementToToggle).hide();
                });
              }
            });
```

So whenever I am adding rows, I am also updating tablesorter table, But column filter just filters the initial rows not the dynamically added rows.